# Edit notification bar bug in review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues

I was going through the 'First Posts' review queue and began to edit a particular question.

Before I could save my edit, I was told another edited had been submitted so mine needed to be more thorough than the existing one in order for it to be submitted. Fine, no issues with that, that's always been the case.

However, once my edit was submitted, and I clicked "I'm Done", the notification bar at the top was still there, even though I was on a different post.

Even on reaching the end of the queue (2 more questions), it was still there, as this image shows.

[image]

I know it's super easy to just click the x to get rid of it, but should it not/wouldn't it be better if it closed by itself once the edit has submitted/the user moves on to the next post in the queue?

Just curious really.